# Getting error when setting up local environment for Facebook app via Heroku

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku, facebook-apps

I have made all the set up that is needed for developing a Facebook app locally via Heroku in PHP.

But after all the things I am getting an error like this:
[image: Facebook SDK Not Found Error]

I understood that the error is for not finding the facebook.php file within sdk folder. But problem is how to get that one. As I didn't receive anything from Heroku. So how to get that one?

Answer (score 3):

Heroku loads the sdk asynchronously when you are developing on Heroku server. For local development, you need to `git clone` the sdk. You can find the sdk in this location: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Clone the sdk into your app folder and it should work fine.

Comment: Okay. I have copied the src folder into the cloned folder that heroku provided. After that I was getting an error saying, "could not resolve graph.facebook.com" Then I connect to the internet. ( But I don't find any reason because it was supposed to be offline). After connecting to the internet I am now getting error that "could not find FacebookApiException" like this.
Please tell me how to activate it for offline.

and if possible can I get an offline documentation of facebook APIs?

Comment: Developing locally does not mean offline. Your app will still have to communicate with the FB server to retrieve the information. I don't think there is any way to use the FB API in an offline mode as you call it, unless you managed to create a database on your local machine with all the user data which, incidentally, maybe illegal.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Any idea of that error? I have not edited a single line of code that Heroku provided. Still with internet-connected, I am getting these errors.

Comment: Have you modified your php.ini file to include the sdk? You will have to modify the line in your ini file that starts with `include_path` and enter the directory where your local SDK resides.